# Modelling Time Series data with tags

Tags: cassandra, time-series

I'm currently working on a poc to model time series data.

The initial datapoint structure:
- the name of a sensor: 192.168.1.1:readCount
- a timestamp
- a value

I use the sensor name as rowid, the timestamp as column id. This approach works very fine.

However I want to add tags to add additional data.

```
public class Datapoint {
   public String metricName;
   public long timestampMs;
   public long value;
   public Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

Datapoint datapoint = new Datapoint();
datapoint.metricName = "IMap.readCount";
datapoint.value = 10;
datapoint.timestampMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
datapoint.tags.put("cluster", "dev");
datapoint.tags.put("member", "192.168.1.1:5701");
datapoint.tags.put("id", "map1");
datapoint.tags.put("company", "Foobar");
```

I want to use it to say: 
- aggregate all metrics for all different machines with the same id. E.g. if machine 1 has 10 writes for mapx, and machine2 did 20 writes for mapx, I want to know that 30.
- aggregate metrics for for all maps: if machine 1 did 20 writes on mapx and 30 writes on mapy, I want to know the total of 50.

The question is how I should model this.

I know that a composite can be used for the column id. So in theory I could add each tag as a an element in that composite. But can a column be efficiently searched for when it has a variable number of elements in the composite?

I know my question is a bit foggy, but I think this reflects my understanding of Cassandra since I just started with it.

Comment: I'm willing to give up flexible tags btw. Having a bunch of fixed tags like member, cluster, company and id will be good enough (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

@pveentjer

"I know that a composite can be used for the column id. So in theory I could add each tag as a an element in that composite. But can a column be efficiently searched for when it has a variable number of elements in the composite?"

There are some rules and restrictions when using multiple composites, read **[here](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Queries#clustering-components-validation-rules)** and **[here](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Queries#clustering-components-ordering-rules)**

For CQL3, there are further limitations, read **[here](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Queries#known-limitations)**